# How do I append a method to __init__ attribute

Tags: python, class

I have made the following class:

```
class Netflix:

    def __init__(self, productions):
        self.productions = []


    def read_productions_csv(self, path):
        with open(path, encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as file:
            open_file = csv.reader(file)
            next(file)

            lst = []
            for x in open_file:

                if x[7] == '' or x[7] == ',':
                    x[7] = "Unknown"
                if x[1] == "Movie":
                    x[1] = 0
                else:
                    x[1] = 1
            
                b = Production(int(x[1]), str(x[2]), str(x[5]), int(x[7]), [(x[3])], [(x[4])], [(x[10])])
            self.productions.append(b)



path = os.path.abspath('../data/netflix.csv')
Netflix.read_productions_csv(path)
```

I want to append the Production class to the self.productions attribute, however this doesn't work.

```
TypeError: read_productions_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

Comment: You must create an instance of the class and call the method on it.

Comment: You need an instance of the class, like `nf = Netflix(your_productions); nf.read_productions_csv(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code below had few issues.
Compare it with your original code.

Once you will add the `Production` class it should work.

```
import csv
import os
class Netflix:

    def __init__(self):
        self.productions = []


    def read_productions_csv(self, path):
        with open(path, encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as file:
            open_file = csv.reader(file)
            next(file)    
            for x in open_file:
                if x[7] == '' or x[7] == ',':
                    x[7] = "Unknown"
                if x[1] == "Movie":
                    x[1] = 0
                else:
                    x[1] = 1
            
                b = Production(int(x[1]), str(x[2]), str(x[5]), int(x[7]), [(x[3])], [(x[4])], [(x[10])])
                self.productions.append(b)



path = os.path.abspath('../data/netflix.csv')
# creating an instance of Netflix
netflix = Netflix()
netflix.read_productions_csv(path)
```